# Cannot get first value of array from generic function (Angular)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a generic method to get data from back-end and pass it to an array

Here is the code of the method, where  I pass method for getting data, array and default value, where I need to write the first element id

```
    interface fillDropdownOptionsInterface {
    method: Observable<ListResultDtoOfDropdownOptionDto>;
    items: SelectItem[];
    defaultvalue?: number;
}
    public static fillDropdownOptionsObj(ref: fillDropdownOptionsInterface): void {
        ref.method.subscribe(r =>
            r.items.forEach(value => {
                ref.items.push({
                    label: value.name,
                    value: value.id,
                });
                ref.defaultvalue = ref.items[0].value;
            })
        );
    }
```

here is how I call it

```
  getQuoteTypes(): void {
    const obj = {
        method: this._quoteService.getQuoteTypesOptions(),
        items: this.quoteTypes,
        defaultvalue: this.quote.quoteTypeId,
    };
    DropdownHelpers.fillDropdownOptionsObj(obj);
}
```

and then I call it in the OnInit method.

My problem that when I want to get  `quoteTypeId` at an HTML template like this, I got nothing.

```
<div class="col-4">
                        <p-dropdown
                            [disabled]="!quoteTypes"
                            [options]="quoteTypes"
                            autoWidth="false"
                            styleClass="w-100"
                            name="quoteType"
                            [autoWidth]="true"
                            [(ngModel)]="quote.quoteTypeId"
                        ></p-dropdown>
                    </div>
                    {{ quote.quoteTypeId }}
```

I was trying to pass a pre-initialized value to pass it to function, and after this function need to rewrite it and pop outside rewrote value.
Like this

```
this.quote.quoteTypeId = 99;
```

But on view, I still see 99.

So I guess the problem in this - function, not pop outside rewrote value (I mean `this.quote.quoteTypeId`). How I can fix this?

Comment: when you call to fillDropdownOptionsObj, you send an object that has no value outside the function getQuoteTypes. The object makes reference to this.quoteTypes (that is an array, OK) but make reference to this.quote.quoteTypeId, that is a string (or number), so only change obj.defaultvalue, NOT this.quote.quoteTypeId, you must, after call the function fillDropdownOptionsObj, equal `this.quote.quoteTypeId==obj.defaultvalue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your helper`DropdownHelpers.fillDropdownOptionsObj(obj)` you overwrite the value of `default` but it seems that you wanted to assign the the the value to `quote.quoteTypeId`.

Maybe you can try the following:

```
<div class="col-4">
  <p-dropdown
     [disabled]="!obj.items"
     [options]="obj.items"
     autoWidth="false"
     styleClass="w-100"
     name="quoteType"
     [autoWidth]="true"
     [(ngModel)]="obj.defaultvalue">
 </p-dropdown>
</div>
{{ quote.quoteTypeId }}
```

I changed every place referencing to `quote` to reference to `obj` instead.

Second suggestion:

Change `this.quote.quoteTypeId` to `this.quote`:

```
 getQuoteTypes(): void {
    const obj = {
        method: this._quoteService.getQuoteTypesOptions(),
        items: this.quoteTypes,
        defaultvalue: this.quote,
    };
    DropdownHelpers.fillDropdownOptionsObj(obj);
}
```

And then, in your handler, assign your id like so `ref.defaultvalue.quoteTypeId = ref.items[0].value`:

```
public static fillDropdownOptionsObj(ref: fillDropdownOptionsInterface): void {
        ref.method.subscribe(r =>
            r.items.forEach(value => {
                ref.items.push({
                    label: value.name,
                    value: value.id,
                });
                ref.defaultvalue.quoteTypeId = ref.items[0].value;
            })
        );
    }
```

Comment: obj is not visible in component html

Comment: made an edit to the answer adding a "second suggestion"

Comment: But it good for one field `quoteTypeId`. I need more generic stuff, so I can pass `quoteTypeId` or `customerTypeId` , or smth else, at your approach, I need to write 2 functions. One for `quoteTypeId` and other for `customerTypeId` , etc.

Comment: you can set another property of `ref.defaultvalue`, i.e.: `ref.defaultvalue.customerTypeId`. In any case, the provided code is very specific so this is pretty much as far as i can assist. You won't get a good answer with a partial code example...